# I don't have border on react-bootstrap-table-next

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I use react-bootstrap-table-next in this way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import products from './data.js';
import 'react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';

const columns = [{
  dataField: 'id',
  text: 'Product ID'
}, {
  dataField: 'name',
  text: 'Product Name'
}, {
  dataField: 'price',
  text: 'Product Price'
}];

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ products } columns={ columns } />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But, there is no border.

[image]

What I'm missing?

Comment: Try removing import 'react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css';

Comment: It doesn't help. But, that file is necessary by documentation.

Comment: I'm sorry. It is required. Please check css files is loaded or not in network calls in browser

Comment: check your bootstrap version, they are compatible with bootstrap 3 only.
You can find this here.
https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: There is no CSS file.

Comment: I've created my react app by using Visual Studio Code with: create-react-app my-app.

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the creator of react-bootstrap-table, please check https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/getting-started.html.

obviously, you are missing to add bootstrap css or there're some problem when you add bootstrap css.

Allen

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue. It requires bootstrap CSS like others mentioned. In a typical react app, you'll want to install `bootstrap` via npm and then import the bootstrap CSS with this line.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import products from './data.js';
import 'react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';

const columns = [{
  dataField: 'id',
  text: 'Product ID'
}, {
  dataField: 'name',
  text: 'Product Name'
}, {
  dataField: 'price',
  text: 'Product Price'
}];

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <BootstrapTable
        keyField="id"
        data={ products }
        columns={ columns }
        striped
        hover
        condensed
     />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Try this.

Comment: It doesn't help.

Comment: Try adding this
bordered = true in BootstrapTable

Comment: react-bootstrap-table2 need you to add bootstrap css in your application firstly. About bootstrap css, we only compatible with bootstrap 3 but will start to compatible for bootstrap 4 on v0.2.0

This is as per official documentation. 
Can you take check ?

Comment: How to check it?

Comment: All their examples work correctly, but my basic sample doesn't work. In the same browser.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap reference needs to be added to index.html as below:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/